# Get Datetime in 8601 format from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

My table stores datetime in the following generic format:

```
2021-03-13 21:29:51.000
```

How can I get the date in this format

```
2021-03-13T21:00-04:00
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT FORMAT (FromDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:00') 
FROM [table]
```

and I get this result: `2021-03-13T13:00`

How can I get the time zone information?

Comment: How is SQL Server supposed to know the timezone?

Comment: *Magic* @GordonLinoff .

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can I not use the same timezone as the server itself?

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you.  I did see that answer before but how can I get the timezone part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a minor nitpick: "*My table stores datetime in the following generic format:*" Uh, no. If you use a field of type `datetime`, the value is stored in some *binary* format and the format you mentioned is just the "default" format SQL Server Management Studio presents to you.

---

That having been said, let's get to work. Since teaching a man how to fish is better than giving him a fish, I will explain the research steps involved in detail.

So you want to add time zone information. Let's have a look at the documentation of T-SQL's `FORMAT` function:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> The format argument must contain a valid .NET Framework format string, [...] A good starting point is the topic, "Formatting Types."

Following the link on "Formatting Types" leads us to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types, which contains a link called "Custom Date and Time Format Strings", finally leading us to

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

which tells us that `zzz` is the time zone format specifier:

```
SELECT FORMAT(FromDateTime,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:00zzz') FROM [table]
```

Now, it's entirely possible that the time zone value determined by SQL Server is not the correct one (especially if you use a data type such as `datetime` which does not store time zone information; you'd need [datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for that). Thus, if you want to use the *fixed value* `-04:00`, this can be done by literally adding it to the end of your format string:

```
SELECT FORMAT(FromDateTime,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:00-04:00') FROM [table]
```

Comment: We need to ensure 1) the OP has defined is column correctly (e.g. as a binary [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql)), and 2) the OP understands that the corresponding datetime value stored on the server is INDEPENDENT OF TIME ZONES!

Comment: @paulsm4: 2) Not necessarily: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @paulsm4: 1) I'm pretty sure of that, otherwise `FORMAT` wouldn't work (which it does, according to the OP). The OP has just the (common) misconception that datetimes are stored with a format (which they obviously aren't).

Comment: @paulsm4: 2) But I've added a comment to my answer to point out that the "default" datetime type does not store timezone information.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  This "common misconception" is definitely more than a "minor nitpick".  It's really ESSENTIAL to understanding how to effectively use datetime values.

Comment: @Heinzi Great.  Thank you so much.  One other question I had was, if I store it as datetimeoffset,  how can I retrieve the same information with timezone?

Comment: @MAK: With `zzz`? I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question...